# how to split this type of string?

Tags: python, string, parsing, split

```
row_data=" 'NULL','to_date(to_char(to_date('19700101'',''YYYYMMDD') + interval '1s' * logevent_timestamp_seconds',''YYYY-MM-DD')',''YYYY-MM-DD')','NULL'"

row_data_list = row_data.split("\',\'")
```

I want to split the data accordingly into three objects

- NULL
- to_date(to_char(to_date('19700101'',''YYYYMMDD') + interval '1s'* logevent_timestamp_seconds',''YYYY-MM-DD')',''YYYY-MM-DD')
- NULL

I cannot hard code it so that it can split it. Is there any way to do it, apart from hard coding and detecting it?

I'm reading the data row_data from a file

Comment: Do you always have 3 values?

Comment: No they don't have 3 values, but I can get the count everytime.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string by `,`, then trim the `'` from both sides for every element:

```
>>> row_data=" 'NULL','to_date(to_char(to_date('19700101'',''YYYYMMDD') + interval '1s' * logevent_timestamp_seconds',''YYYY-MM-DD')',''YYYY-MM-DD')','NULL'"
>>> row_data_list = list(map(lambda x: x[1:-1], row_data.strip().split(',')))
>>> row_data_list
['NULL', "to_date(to_char(to_date('19700101'", "'YYYYMMDD') + interval '1s' * logevent_timestamp_seconds", "'YYYY-MM-DD')", "'YYYY-MM-DD')", 'NULL']
```

This will work for every string styled that way, with every number of elements.

Comment: If you do the length  then it would come to 6, But what I want is NULL,something,NULL which makes len(row_data_list) as 3

Comment: then you need to iterate through the parenthesizes, unless you want to just split by 'NULL' and then add nulls of your own. The string you provide contains both , and ',' in the middle of the text, and as saparators.

Comment: for that use `row_data_list = ['NULL', row_data.strip().split('NULL')[1][3:-3], 'NULL']`